# TLS offloading done by IIS or Windows

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, tls1.2

I recently learnt that TLS negotiation is done by the Windows Server. But, in IIS we can bind SSL certificate for specific domain. Doesn't it means that IIS takes care of TLS offloading? Is this true, even when we configure IIS as reverse proxy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: TLS is done by Windows networking modules, and IIS also relies on that.

Comment: So, what you mean is that, the request comes to IIS, IIS hands over to windows networking modules for verification, then result is declared to IIS whether the handshake is success. Right?

Comment: the request comes to Windows networking first and then IIS.